# how to open an iframe in a lightbox on click of a button

Tags: html, css, iframe, fancybox

I want to open an iframe in a lightbox onclick of a button.

I am using [fancybox lightbox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for this. But, I am not able to integrate all this.

This is my code:

```
<div class="mx-header">
       <div class="mx-header-container">
           <a href="http://iradio.s.widget.ldrhub.com/releases/4/index.php?key=iradio&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iradio.ie%2F" title="itakeover" class="itakeover" target="_blank" >iTakeover</a>
         </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
.itakeover{
position: relative;
width: 80px; height: 20px; 
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffc400 , #ff7600);
color: white !important;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 9px 40px !important;
top: 30px;
left: 100px;
```

}

and this is the screenshot to my page. http://uploadpie.com/R3n3P

I want to do this, on the itakeover button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize fancybox targeting the *class* selector `itakeover` and set the `type` to `iframe` like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".itakeover").fancybox({
    // API options
    type: "iframe"
  }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/picssel/v0odbkf1/)**

Answer (score 0):

the only issue is the aspect ratio of a modal window with iframe content. I use [**iframe-lightbox**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-lightbox) that is easy to setup a 16:9 4:3 or whatever dimensions you need.

- Nicely fits YouTube / Vimeo / SoundCloud or other URL via iframe
- Customizable aspect ratio via data-padding-bottom attribute
- Debounced launch, default 500ms, custom rate can be set as second parameter
- Preloading spinner that is unset after onload event succeeds